# Problems with re-sizing a partition in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, partitioning, filesystem, disk, hyper-v

I'm running an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS VM in Hyper-V. I recently resized a VHDX disk from 15GB to 100GB. Then I tried to use `parted` and `resizepart 1 100%`. After that nothing had really change.

df -h:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           790M  1,5M  789M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        12G  9,9G  1,6G  87% /
tmpfs           3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop1       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2721
/dev/loop2       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1518
/dev/loop3       64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1852
/dev/loop7       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/loop6       82M   82M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
/dev/loop4      255M  255M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/106
/dev/loop5      350M  350M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/137
/dev/loop8      263M  263M     0 100% /snap/nextcloud/33908
/dev/loop9       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/558
/dev/loop11      50M   50M     0 100% /snap/snapd/18596
/dev/loop10      46M   46M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/638
/dev/sda15      105M  5,2M  100M   5% /boot/efi
tmpfs           790M   20K  790M   1% /run/user/125
tmpfs           790M   28K  790M   1% /run/user/1000
```

[Disks app shows that my ext4 is 100GB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfHim.jpg)

I'm stuck. I have no idea what to do next:/ Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the filesystem in the picture: ext4

To resize the filesystem to fit the partition size you need to run `resize2fs` (see `man resize2fs` for details).

From the infos of the question, this should do the job. If not, check manpage.

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
```